# What are the disadvantages of using custom queries in Cognos?

Tags: cognos

We are utilizing IBM Cognos and one of the developers recommended users NOT to use custom queries.

We didn't get a rationale for this recommendation so hoping to understand here from somebody about the pros/cons of custom vs native querying in Cognos.

Comment: "custom queries" could mean you are editing queries directly in the report rather than dragging and dropping objects onto a page.  Based on your comment on VAI Jason's answer, I suspect you are asking specifically about queries that use the SQL object -- allowing the user to type the entire query in Cognos SQL, Native SQL, or Pass-thru SQL.  You should clarify that in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great question

To create your own custom SQL is tempting:
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cognos-analytics/11.1.0?topic=mdx-build-report-using-your-own-sql

Cognos as a business intelligence solution hinges on a few key points

1. Consistent approach
2. Avoiding data traps/Remove ambiguity
3. Easier to maintain and test/Option for embedded security at the data layer
   etc

- Consistent approach:
  If users are able to create their own SQL, then they lose out on leveraging a package created in framework manager.  Which means each author may have a different way of reporting that returns different results (and damages the credibility of the product).  Also, if something changes in your database, you have to change it in every single report, instead of changing it once in the model.
- Avoiding data traps:
  By using a model, the report authors can construct an analysis without having to worry too much about the technical layer.  Data traps would include things like the cross product or assumptions about joins to tables or data patterns.  There are bunch of data traps, it could become it's own topic.  A common example of one is the ambiguity trap where there is more than one way to describe an attribute. For example, It could be date.  It's too vague.  In a model it would be described in more detail to avoid ambiguity -- invoice date, order date, requested ship date, etc.
- Easier to maintain/test & option for embedded security at the data layer
  By having a metadata package published, there is only one version of SQL to test/maintain.  Adding new data items can be as simple as a few minutes  vs modifying a SQL statement that could be hundreds of lines long and difficult to read.

Also, custom sql means the user is bypassing the SQL in the package and they could query anything in the data layer that they have object authority to.  By following the model, the user is limited to only what was designed in framework manager.
If you want to get fancy, you can embed filters on the tables in the model to control how the data looks and what a user can access

Comment: Woah didnt expect such a detailed breakdown, you're awesome! Just to elaborate during my presentation of rationale to users, could you add on to the answer some pros of custom querying aside from bypassing the sql?

Comment: And this is one of the problems with Cognos.  Security is not granular enough.  As a Cognos administrator, I have legitimate needs to write custom SQL in a handful of Cognos reports.  But I know the data structures far better than my users do.  In order for my users to be able to consume these reports, I must allow them to write custom SQL.  There's no "view only" option for this feature.  So it turns into an "all or nothing" scenario.

Comment: @dougp can you give an example of what you wanted Cognos security to do?
Maybe there is a away to accomplish what you want?

Comment: @Cataster asked for pros to a custom query approach - 1) probably the biggest pro is if you already have working SQL and you want to save development time (instead of converting existing SQL into a model)  2) User can perform analysis and they do not need access to framework manager tool (currently a windows only product).   3) helpful for testing/development to try out a concept before building a complex model.  This is more of a role change from an author to a programming role/task 4) Less rigid than a model (usually we want rigid for the reasons stated above - consistency, security, etc).

Comment: I want to allow all users to run a report that uses SQL, but only administrators should be able to edit SQL in a report.

Comment: dougp, what have you tried?   Did you try this with setting a user capabilities?  Maybe allow one group of authors to have User Defined SQL and the other group of authors would not

Answer (score 2):

You want to create a best practices / proven practices model.  This model will adhere to the Kimball data warehouse structure.

It will have exposed objects which an ordinary user can drag and drop into a report or dashboard and create a meaningful, accurate report without needing to ask some guy in a report writing team, who might get around to it in a couple of weeks and might not actually understand what is being asked of him. It will liberate business users from the tyranny of the IT crowd.

It will also have advanced stuff for report authors like summary tables and other queries, which, because they exist in the model, do not need to be recreated for each report.

Because these things are written once, there is only one point of failure. Because it exists in a model and not in a bunch of reports, there will be consistency. No one thing could mean something slightly different or produce slightly different results between reports. You might have come across people talking about 'the single version of the truth'.  That is what they are trying to get at.

No report should be static.  It's the third decade of the 21st century.

Cognos query engine decomposes queries to attempt to push the maximum to the data base or data bases.  A hodgepodge of custom queries doesn't necessarily work as well as that.

Clever but misguided people try to shoehorn the reporting tool into being a SQL writer.  It can do it but *that's not the point*.

Comment: Lol love the comments ”It's the third decade of the 21st century.”